# Having issues transferring high dollar amount from thailand to us

Tags: banking

Thailand Bank is telling us we need to get anti money laundering paperwork for 5% of what is in our account or we can boycott and pay the bank 2% of what is

Comment: This doesn’t answer the question, but are you 100% aware of the origin of the money in the Thailand bank? I ask because a common hallmark of a scam is that the victim has to pay some amount of money to supposedly get access to a much larger sum, and this smells like it might be that sort of issue.

Comment: Are you trying to transfer your OWN money?  or someone is asking you to help them transfer THEIR money?

Answer (score 2):

### It's a scam. There is no money waiting for you. Run.

Your short description sounds very much like you're being set up as the victim of an [advance-fee scam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advance-fee_scam).

The scammer will promise you that you can get a large sum of money (the reasons for this vary; they're invented out of thin air). Only when the money is about to be transferred to there turns out to be a small bureaucratic matter which needs some money to up front to resolve -- much less than the windfall that you've been promised so you happily put up some money of your own. Once this snag has been "resolved" another one will materialize. The big sum of money never shows up -- it never existed in the first place, and the whole thing is all a ruse to steal the "up front" money you provided.

Yes, that is a lot of conclusion to jump from from a line and a half of question. What clinches it for me is that the people you're talking to suggest **bribing the bank** 2% of the sum to omit some expensive legally-required bureaucracy. It is a common feature of advance-fee scams to tell you that the money you provide are to be used for bribes and similar illegal purposes.

If you willingly put up money for the "bribe", they can use it as blackmail material to extort more money from you later in the scam *("ooh splat, something went wrong with the anti-laundering bribe and the Thai banking regulator is about to find out. We can't afford to cover it up ourselves, and they're going to tell the FBI and you'll go to jail too. Unless you can help fund a better cover-up, that is ...")*. In reality, of course, nobody has even been bribed, and the scammers simply pocket all the money you send them.

---

(Banks do have to follow some anti-laundering safeguards for large international transactions. But they are nowhere as expensive as 5% of the transaction amount -- international finance would grind to a halt if that were the case).